# ui-bootstrap how to get the scope in view aliased

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

[View calling modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rLIV.png)

I have this code you should: open a modal bringing the data within the controller being used by the angular-ui-bootstrap. But it is not getting the result of the "item" that is selected.

in my controller:

```
function EntidadesCtrlFn(EntidadeService, $uibModal, $log) {
 var vm = this;
 vm.animationsEnabled = true;
 vm.modalEdit = function(size, selectedEntidade) {

  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: vm.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: './app/modulos/entidades/views/edit-entidades.html',
    controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, entidade) {
      vm.entidade = entidade;
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    size: size,
    resolve: {
      entidade: function() {
        return selectedEntidade;
      }
    }
  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
    vm.selected = selectedItem;
  }, function() {
    console.log('Modal dismissed.result.');
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
};
```

in view of list:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="EntidadesCtrl as vm">
...
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.modalEdit('lg', entidade)" type="button">
  Editar
</button>
...
```

This modal opens, but does not bring the contents of:

```
controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, entidade) {
      vm.entidade = entidade;
    },
```

TemplateUrl:

```
<section ng-controller="EntidadesCtrl as vm">
 {{vm}}
 <div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Editando entidade</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  ...
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" type="button">OK</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()" type="button">Cancel</button>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why pass it through the view? Why not just access 'entidade' inside your controller?

Comment: And please tell me you're not creating a controller for each data row...

Comment: @cxminer, thanks for the answer.

I am creating a controller for each function (edit, create and list);

I need to get "inside" the modal the item that is being edited;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
I ended up forgetting to pass "this" in the controller ;

Sorry about that.

In the controller modal:

```
controller: function($uibModalInstance, entidade) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.entidade = entidade;
},
```

Comment: Thanks @cxminer for u time